# Laravel4 response should be prompted to save as file

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm trying to write a response to be saved to file in client side rather than opened in browser's window. Here's what I'm doing

```
$content = 'Some content.';
$response = \Response::make($content, 200);
$response->header('Content-Description', 'File Transfer');
$response->header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
$response->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=somecontent.any);
$response->header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', 'binary');
$response->header('Expires', '0');
$response->header('Cache-Control', 'must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
$response->header('Pragma', 'public');
$response->header('Content-Length', strlen($content));
return $response;
```

Unfortunately, it does not start download as file. When I look at the response headers in Firefox, I'm getting this:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.3
Server: Apache
Pragma: public
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Expires: 0
Date: Mon, 27 Jan 2014 11:34:23 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
content-transfer-encoding: binary
Content-Length: 13
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somecontent.any
Content-Description: File Transfer
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, private

Unknown Content Type
Unable to display responses of type "application/octet-stream"
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong here.

Since the extension varies I can't hardcode it to server's configuration. But client wants the contents to be opened as file download rather than directly in browser's window.

Now I know the problem is related to the fact the original query was sent as an ajax post. If I give that as a response to a regular link click then it works fine (starts a download immediately). But if the query is posted from JavaScript then it does not start a download but tries to open it in the browser's window no matter I give to headers. Is there a way to make it work this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this and it works well!

```
// $config contains generated XML file as string.
$config = $this->generateConfig('apple', Input::all());

// Make response -> attach $config to response
$response = Response::make($config);

// Set headers
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/x-apple-aspen-config');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename='mail.mobileconfig'");

return $response;
```

Comment: Thank you. No difference... :(
What if it has something to do with the fact the original query was an ajax post?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Response::download($pathToFile)` method for this. See the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses) for more options.

Comment: Thanks. The contents is not a saved file but generated dynamically according to the ajax query.

Comment: The same problem exists even if I used Response::download for a previously saved file. It does not go to downloads. I wonder if it's related to the fact the original query was sent as ajax post.

Comment: It is, because I tested it with direct link and it would start a download immediately. So, what is different when the original query is an ajax post? Is there a way to force downloading in this case?

Comment: Using AJAX, you can return response (text in html, json, whatever) but you cannot force browser to download that response as file using JavaScript. Instead return generatel URL in AJAX, redirect user to that URL and let him download the file.